# Leiningen commands suddenly return errors

Tags: clojure, leiningen

When running `lein` commands, I get this error:

```
Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.cognitect:transit-clj:jar:0.8.309
```

I have no clue what's going on, I've had the error for a day now. These are my dependencies:

```clj
  :dependencies [[ch.qos.logback/logback-classic "1.2.9"]
                 [com.novemberain/validateur "2.6.0"]
                 [com.timezynk/assembly-line "1.0.0"]
                 [com.timezynk/useful "1.19.0"]
                 [compojure "1.7.0" :scope "provided"]
                 [congomongo "2.5.1" :scope "provided"]
                 [org.clojure/clojure "1.11.1" :scope "provided"]
                 [org.clojure/tools.logging "1.2.4"]
                 [slingshot "0.12.2"]
                 [tortue/spy "2.4.0"]]
```

Edit: It looks like a Maven error, and maybe it is, but I don't know anything about Maven, and I can't find any info that is readable to me.

Comment: What happens after `rm -rf ~/.m2/repository/com/cognitect/transit-clj/0.8.309 && lein deps` ?

Comment: @Julia I don't know how to use that information. It's specifically for Maven.

Comment: @cfrick Didn't change anything unfortunately.

Answer (score -1):

Found a solution. Completely cleaning out the repository solved the issue:

```bash
cd ~/.m2/repository
sudo rm -rf *
```

Comment: Why would `sudo` be needed here?

Comment: @cfrick It doesn't work without it.

Comment: Then you are doing things partially with a different user, which is a bad idea. And the reason most likely why this helped is because lein/aether/whatever could not write or update inside this tree. Stop "fixing" problems by putting `sudo` in front of commands.